# Specs and Functionalities of Nook E reader(Developer Thoughts)?

Tags: android, ipad, nook

What are the things that an android developer does to achieve it. So I need to know the basic functionality difference of IPad and other E-readers. I heard about Nook which runs an Android operating system. How do I test my app on that nook, i.e. is there any emulator configuration to test the application of nook?  (Because I don't have nook now.) Can you post your suggestions to efficiently develop the application for nook e-reader?

Edit:

I need to know the following:

- What SDK to use for the nook Android
  platform.
- Configuration needs of An Emulator on
  AVD.
- Special key functionalities, like
  previous/next page.
- Specs and Functionality of Nook.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the color of your bikeshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nook does not run third party apps at this time, except via [rooting the device](http://www.nookdevs.com/Main_Page). Hence, there is no official developer support for the nook.

Answer (score 1):

In the not too distant future there will be a Nook store that will allow you to add third party applications.  For more information see [The nook developer website](http://nookdeveloper.barnesandnoble.com/)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, there isn't any sort of third-party developing you can do for the nook, so any modifications you make are only available to users who root the device.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently possible.

I used the emulator exclusively to test my app (since I don't own a Nook yet), and I was able to pass QA.  I posted a few of the Nook-specific gotchas that you need to be careful of (including some things that are different between the emulator and the real thing:

http://www.projectjourneyman.com/android-alternate-market-review-nook-store-2

Answer (score 0):

Update to an old question -- NOOK devices do accept 3rd party apps submitted through the NOOK developer program: http://nookdeveloper.com and sold through the Barnes & Noble storefront.

Tom